# sql regex parse text to add in new lines

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I am trying to take a notes field that is just a big block of text, sample data is below as if I were inserting it into a table.

```
create table test_table
(
job_number number,
notes varchar2(4000)
)

insert into test_table (job_number,notes)
values (12345,1022089483 notes notes notes notes 1022094450 notes notes notes notes 1022095218 notes notes notes notes)
```

I need to parse it out so there is a separate record for each notes entry (the 10 digit numbers leading the notes are unix timestamps). so if i were to export to pipe delimited it would look like this:

> job_number|notes
>
> 12345|1022089483 notes notes notes notes
>
> 12345|1022094450 notes notes notes notes
>
> 12345|1022095218 notes notes notes notes

I really hope this makes sense. I appreciate any insight.

Comment: i assume the number of notes per row varies? also what version of oracle are you on?

Comment: yes, number of notes varies. I think we are on 8 or 9. regex is not built in, but we have created functions to perform some regex stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a few ways of doing this:

```
SQL> insert into test_table (job_number,notes)
  2  values (12345,'1022089483 notes notes notes notes 1022094450 notes notes notes notes 1022095218 notes notes notes notes');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into test_table (job_number,notes)
  2  values (12346,'1022089483 notes notes notes notes 1022094450 foo 1022095218 test notes 1022493228 the answer is 42');

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.
```

note: i'm using `[0-9]{10}` as my regex to determine the note (ie any 10 digit number is considered the start of the note).

first up, we can take the approach of calculating the max number of notes in any given row, and then do a cartesian join with that number of rows. then filter out each note:

```
SQL> with data
  2  as (select job_number, notes,
  3            (length(notes)-length(regexp_replace(notes, '[0-9]{10}', null)))/10 num_of_notes
  4        from test_table t)
  5  select job_number,
  6         substr(d.notes, regexp_instr(d.notes, '[0-9]{10}', 1, rn.l),
  7                       regexp_instr(d.notes||' 0000000000', '[0-9]{10}', 1, rn.l+1)
  8                       -regexp_instr(d.notes, '[0-9]{10}', 1, rn.l) -1
  9               ) note
 10    from data d
 11         cross join (select rownum l
 12                      from dual
 13                    connect by level <= (select max(num_of_notes)
 14                                           from data)) rn
 15   where rn.l <= d.num_of_notes
 16   order by job_number, rn.l;

JOB_NUMBER NOTE
---------- --------------------------------------------------
     12345 1022089483 notes notes notes notes
     12345 1022094450 notes notes notes notes
     12345 1022095218 notes notes notes notes
     12346 1022089483 notes notes notes notes
     12346 1022094450 foo
     12346 1022095218 test notes
     12346 1022493228 the answer is 42

7 rows selected.
```

that is ok as long as the number of notes is generally the same (the bigger the differences 
the worse this scales, as we are doing a lot of recursive lookups).

in 11g we could use a resursive factored sub query to do the same thing as above, but doesn't do extra looping:

```
SQL> with data (job_number, notes, note, num_of_notes, iter)
  2  as (select job_number, notes,
  3             substr(notes, regexp_instr(notes, '[0-9]{10}', 1, 1),
  4                    regexp_instr(notes||' 0000000000', '[0-9]{10}', 1, 2)
  5                    -regexp_instr(notes, '[0-9]{10}', 1, 1) -1
  6                  ),
  7             (length(notes)-length(regexp_replace(notes, '[0-9]{10}', null)))/10 num_of_notes,
  8             1
  9        from test_table
 10      union all
 11     select job_number, notes,
 12             substr(notes, regexp_instr(notes, '[0-9]{10}', 1, iter+1),
 13                    regexp_instr(notes||' 0000000000', '[0-9]{10}', 1, iter+2)
 14                    -regexp_instr(notes, '[0-9]{10}', 1, iter+1) -1
 15                  ),
 16             num_of_notes, iter + 1
 17       from data
 18      where substr(notes, regexp_instr(notes, '[0-9]{10}', 1, iter+1),
 19                    regexp_instr(notes||' 0000000000', '[0-9]{10}', 1, iter+2)
 20                    -regexp_instr(notes, '[0-9]{10}', 1, iter+1) -1
 21                  ) is not null
 22    )
 23  select job_number, note
 24    from data
 25  order by job_number, iter;

JOB_NUMBER NOTE
---------- --------------------------------------------------
     12345 1022089483 notes notes notes notes
     12345 1022094450 notes notes notes notes
     12345 1022095218 notes notes notes notes
     12346 1022089483 notes notes notes notes
     12346 1022094450 foo
     12346 1022095218 test notes
     12346 1022493228 the answer is 42

7 rows selected.
```

or from 10g onwards we could use the model clause to make up rows:

```
SQL> with data as (select job_number, notes,
  2                       (length(notes)-length(regexp_replace(notes, '[0-9]{10}', null)))/10 num_of_notes
  3                  from test_table)
  4  select job_number, note
  5    from data
  6  model
  7  partition by (job_number)
  8  dimension by (1 as i)
  9  measures (notes, num_of_notes, cast(null as varchar2(4000)) note)
 10  rules
 11  (
 12    note[for i from 1 to num_of_notes[1] increment 1]
 13      = substr(notes[1],
 14               regexp_instr(notes[1], '[0-9]{10}', 1, cv(i)),
 15               regexp_instr(notes[1]||' 0000000000', '[0-9]{10}', 1, cv(i)+1)
 16               -regexp_instr(notes[1], '[0-9]{10}', 1, cv(i)) -1
 17              )
 18  )
 19  order by job_number, i;

JOB_NUMBER NOTE
---------- --------------------------------------------------
     12345 1022089483 notes notes notes notes
     12345 1022094450 notes notes notes notes
     12345 1022095218 notes notes notes notes
     12346 1022089483 notes notes notes notes
     12346 1022094450 foo
     12346 1022095218 test notes
     12346 1022493228 the answer is 42
```